# Как реализовать загрузку прайсов в интернет-магазин на PHP?

Tags: xml, php, xls, yml

Здравствуйте!

Требуется написать скрипт по загрузке прайс-листов в интернет-магазин. Загрузка может осуществляться из разных источников, поэтому необходимо учесть все возможные варианты. Я так понял, что есть несколько основных стандартов - это XLS, XML и YML.

По поводу YML ситуация более-менее ясна, есть документация Яндекса. А вот с XLS беда, может, гуглю не так, в общем, нужна ваша помощь...

Есть ли готовые решения на PHP для загрузки прайс-листов в этих форматах?
Где найти инфо касаемо XLS и XML? (Или хотя-бы пример этих файлов.)
Может, есть еще какие стандарты?

Answer (score 2):

Решал подобную проблему несколько по-другому (через клиентский JavaScript). Использовал [handsontable.com](http://handsontable.com/). Смысл в том, что когда пользователь сайта хочет загрузить прайс, заходит на страницу с текущим прайсом, очищает его, дальше из Excel-я делает `Ctrl-A`, `Ctrl-C`
Переходит в броузер делает `Ctrl-V`. На уровне JS все что пользователь ввел обрабатывается на уровне JS и отображается через handsontable пользователь видит что у него получилось, и либо правит в броузере, либо в Excel-е.

Решение не идеальное, но для небольших прайс-листов подходит.

Answer (score 0):

1. [PHPExcel](https://phpexcel.codeplex.com/) - проверено, работает отлично, документации море
2. [Хабр](http://habrahabr.ru/company/pechkin/blog/224207/) - тут небольшой обзор библиотек